How to configure your security config class in springboot 3.1.2 so that filter applies only to specific apis?
I am trying to migrate from Springboot 2.7 to Springboot 3.1.2 . I am trying to configure my security config class. This is my class
      @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc) throws Exception {

            http
                    .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer :: disable)
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request.requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/api/dummy/***"))
                            .permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated())
                    .sessionManagement(manager ->manager.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                    .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                    .addFilterBefore(new AuthTokenFilter(serviceA, serviceB),AuthenticationFilter.class);

            return http.build();
        }



I want the /api/dummy/** api to pass without any filter and want the filter to be applied for all the other requests. But currently, all my apis, irrespective of any request matching is going through the addFilterBefore method and going inside AuthTokenFilter class.
Can anyone please help me solve the issue so that the mentioned API does not go through the authTokenFilter and rest of the APIs go.
I have tried to configure the same in all the possible ways found in the internet, still its not working. Any help would be much appreciated.

You have to configure a separate SecurityFilterChain with HttpSecurity#securityMatchers in place for that specific endpoint. Also add @Order to both filter chains, for the /api/dummy/ filter eg 10 and for the other one, which catches all the other endoints 20. This way you can omit setting securityMatchers for the main filter chain at all.

@Slevin could u please share any link about how I can configure it the way u said or write me a sample code for the same.

Why do you even have custom homemade security? Why are you not following the security standards?

@Toerktumlare There is nothing worng with custom homemade security. Sometimes you just have to add some extra features or custom things into the given base security concept. Spring is made for that, so that you can always extend this given base concept. Otherwise Spring would just be a tight and unflexible framework with no wiggleroom, forcing the users to obey whatever Spring decides to be best. As long as one follows current standards and knows the do's and don'ts everything is fine.

Please read my comment again as i have not said snywhere that you shouldnt im asking for the why and i am fully aware of what you can do and not do, and writing a custom security or extending security is two different things. Standards are defined to ensure that most security issues are mitigated. Extending an authenticationProvider is a whole lot different that writing your own custom one. By not using the built in ones you are opting out from for example sessions fixation attacks, and other built in mitigations.

My own experience is that most people writing their own security does not actually know what they are giving up to just solve their small problem. So i prefer that the question asker answers the why than you. Thank you

”There is nothing worng with custom homemade security.” and i strongly disagree with this statement.

@Slevin Thanks I tried out the solution and it seemed to work. Much appreciated

You have to set up two SecurityFilterChain:
@Bean
@Order(10)
public SecurityFilterChain dummyFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc) throws Exception {

    http
        .securityMatchers(matchers -> matchers
            .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/api/dummy/**")))

        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll())

        .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
        .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
@Order(20)
public SecurityFilterChain mainFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc) throws Exception {

    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request.anyRequest().authenticated())

        .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
        .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
        .addFilterBefore(new AuthTokenFilter(serviceA, serviceB), AuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
}

More about Security Matchers here in the Spring Security documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html#security-matchers
